# ERROR ITMS-90023 "Missing required icon file" XCode 8.3.2 Even though file is in assets catalog

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

Full error message: ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions supporting iPad Pro."

The icon for the iPad Pro is in the correct location in the xcassets, which has a space for the iPad Pro icon.  The version this is happening in is XCode 8.3.2.  All the pages I found with this problem were for older versions of XCode, where there wasn't a spot for the iPad Pro icon.

Any light that can be shed on how to make this error go away would be fantastic.  Thanks!

Sincerely,
Sean

Comment: Check if the icon is in correct format. It happens sometimes that a jpeg sits there instead of png.

Comment: I had the same error. Clean, then Build, then recreate archive worked for me.